# how i can do a DND in treeview with model filter in GTK 3 with GTK_SELECTION_MULTIPLE in C?

Tags: c, drag-and-drop, gtk3, gtktreeview

I'm trying to implement a DND solution on 2 GTK treeview with a multiple selection. The single selection works well, but as soon as set the `gtk_tree_selection_set_mode` to `GTK_SELECTION_MULTIPLE` I must change my `on_drag_data_get callback(drag-data-get)`.

The `gtk_tree_selection_get_selected` only works with a single selection. With the multiple selection I use the `gtk_tree_selection_get_selected_rows` to have a glist of selected rows and after I do a `g_list_foreach` with a function to set the `gtk_selection_data` with `gtk_selection_data_set`, but from there I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution, in fact i no longer use the gtk_selection_data to forward my data, it's just use to fired the drag-data-receive.
In my drag-data-get i fill a liststore with all selected rows and in my drag-data-receive i just browse this liststore to fill the target's liststore and it's works well. I know this isn't the best solution but it works...
if that can help...

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.